# Ways to kill off characters on a spacecraft by freezing them to death?

Tags: science-based, technology, spaceships

Looking for ways to kill characters off while in space. The scenario has a group of people trapped in a section of a spaceship either during or just prior to landing on a planet.

Particularly, are there ways they could freeze to death due to hardware malfunction or damage.

If so are there ways in which there could be a major failure of the spacecraft's temperature regulation systems?

Comment: the question is too broad.

Comment: This question is perhaps a bit broad... there are a _lot_ of ways to die on a spacecraft, and requests to "list all the things" aren't really a good fit for this site. Could you be more specific? You're sort of heading in that direction with temperature related stuff, at least.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please note that the Worldbuilding SE is dedicated to providing detailed answers to specific questions you have while developing your fictional world. To that end, questions need to be narrowly defined and constrained such that it is possible to identify a "best" answer to the problem. Barring an [edit], this question is likely to be put on hold as _needs more focus_. Feel free to take the [tour] or check out our [site culture](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6388/6986) to get a better understanding of the site.

Comment: They could slip while taking a shower an hit their head. I mean, taking a scientific shower.

Comment: I'm sorry you were redirected here from SciFi.SE only to have your question closed a second time, but you *were* told to check our help centre and supply more details, and it doesn't appear that you did either.

Comment: I will say that if you do edit your question a bit to be more specific, it can be re-opened. Certainly there are interesting possibilities you haven't considered yet...

Comment: I have to say, your edit makes little sense as it invalidates the answer that you accepted. In any case invalidating an existing up-voted answer by editing is frowned upon. You could ask another question though which addresses the question that you have in mind. (From review).

Comment: Hi, Happytree. I'm evaluating your re-open request. You want us to list different ways to freeze to death? I'm only aware of one way to freeze to death. Certainly if the heat systems fail, the characters will freeze. This answer seems so obvious that I think I've missed the point of your edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you trap some people on a spacecraft in a room without airconditioning, they'll die of *heatstroke*. Without active cooling, it'll get very warm in their compartment, at least body temperature and likely more due to various machinery giving of waste heat. Add to this "while landing on a planet", and it'll get very hot indeed in no time.

[image: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Apollo_cm.jpg]
(Apollo CM reentry from wikipedia)

It would be "refreshing" to see that in a work of sci-fi instead of the old, and wrong, trope of freezing to death.

Comment: Oh, I'm sure this is why the Apollo 13 astronauts were hypothermic before reentry...

Comment: @ZeissIkon https://bit.ly/37L9fMh states that they weren't in danger of hypothermia. and their LM was powered down as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the advice of avoiding the typical trope of freezing to death, which I would indeed like to avoid. However, my reasoning for turning this direction is irrelevant to that stereotype since I'm adapting a very old story and bringing it far into the future. Nonetheless, the tiny detail could change for the reason you mentioned above...

Comment: That *"various machinery giving of waste heat"* includes the cosmonauts themselves... Each of them counts for at least 100 W of waste heat, possibly much more if they actually do something instead of just resting motionless.